# Expo - Deep linking on IOS doesn't open my app inside instagram but in the browser it works

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-linking

I just integrated Deep linking on my app and things are working fine. The app opens in case it's installed and if it don't it goes to the website.

Links coming from whatsapp, browser, email, etc are working fine, but links coming from instagram for some reason it doesn't work.

Do you guys know how I can make it work? I believe its something related to infoPlist

Here is my infoPlist on app.json:

```
"infoPlist": {
    "NSContactsUsageDescription": "Allow our application to access your contacts so you can invite people to events",
    "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Allow our application to use your location so you can see events around you",
    "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Allow our application to access your photos so you can upload photos to your events and your profile",
    "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
    "UIRequiresFullScreen": true,
    "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes": ["fb","fbapi","fbauth2","fb-messenger-api","instagram","tiktok","comgooglemaps","twitter"]
  }
```